# Hello, please tell me the library for admob advertising. Could you tell

Tags: admob

is there a library for displaying ads in an android application only to be embedded in xml.

Hello, please tell me the library for admob advertising. Could you tell

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob

Comment: unofficial does not work so turn on.